I used a 2 workers pool to split a sum in a function with Python multiprocessing but the timing doesn't speed up, is there something I'm missing?
The Python code file is provided below. I'm using Python 3.10.12 on a Linux mint 21.3 (in case any of these info are needed). The one with a pool of 2 workers takes more time than the one without any multiprocessing. What am I doing wrong here?
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

def fun1( x ):
    y = 0
    for i in range( len( x ) ):
        y = y + x[i]
    return( y )

def fun2( x ):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool( 2 )
    y1, y2 = p.map( fun1, [ x[ : len( x ) // 2 ], x[ len( x ) // 2 : ] ] )
    y = y1 + y2
    return( y )

x = [ random.random() for i in range( 10 ** 6 ) ]

st = time.time()
ans = fun1( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

st = time.time()
ans = fun2( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

x = [ random.random() for i in range( 10 ** 7 ) ]

st = time.time()
ans = fun1( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

st = time.time()
ans = fun2( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

Here is what I get in terminal.
time = 0.043381452560424805, answer = 499936.40420325665.
time = 0.1324300765991211, answer = 499936.40420325927.
time = 0.4444568157196045, answer = 5000677.883536603.
time = 0.8388040065765381, answer = 5000677.883536343.

I also used the if __name__ == '__main__': line after fun2 and before the rest, I get the same results on terminal. I also tried Python 3.6.2 on a Codio server. I got similar timings.
time = 0.048882484436035156, answer = 499937.07655266096.
time = 0.15220355987548828, answer = 499937.0765526707.
time = 0.4848289489746094, answer = 4999759.127770024.
time = 1.4035391807556152, answer = 4999759.127769606.

I guess it is something wrong with what I'm doing in my code, a misunderstanding on how to use the multiprocessing.Pool rather than Python, but can't think of what. Any help will be appreciated. I expect using two workers I get a speed up by factor two, not a speed down. Also if needed, I checked with multiprocessing.cpu_count(), the Codio server has 4 and my computer has 12 cpus.

I don't think you're doing anything wrong - but the actual work done in each iteration (1 addition + 1 assignment) is just not expensive enough to outweigh the overhead from splitting and mapping the input and marshalling the extra threads. Try adding time.sleep(0.001) (perhaps with a smaller input size) after each iteration in fun1 - suddenly you'll see the pool finishing faster

@MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the comment. Just to make sure I interpreted your comment correctly, do you mean that the mapping method is not giving the whole fun1 instruction and one of the given inputs to a separate processor, but instead it is picking up one fun1 and one input, then distributing steps of the for-loop to different processors?

No, that's not what I'm saying - everything is working as intended in your posted sample  - but the cumulative overhead from everything that goes into bootstrapping and managing the threadpool simply exceeds the trivial cost of the original workload - splitting the input list into 2 likely contributes to that overhead, although I doubt it's the biggest factor. For the suggested experiment, here's what I meant in terms of changes to fun1: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/IISResetMe/478fc995d9c5e9e78754574c4c98dcff/raw/7b6dd7e58282a034a89eb35a9b742c07f504a800/slower_fun1.py

@MathiasR.Jessen thanks, I think sleep is a good thing to show multithreading and asyncio roles for concurrent programming, and addition for multiprocessing. Now that I think more, I can get along that the line 'y = y + x[i]' is reading and writing on memory so maybe I/O bound, but then what can be a simple cpu-bound task with the minimum I/O-bound overhead etc? Also a second question, why using 2 processor takes more time, their threads are not independent from each other?

sleep() isn't CPU-bound, so using multiple processors in this case won't give you anything other than more scheduling overhead :) For a CPU-bound workload, do something that requires many CPU instructions in quick succession: a simple (=unoptimized) primality test over large integers, multiplying big matrices, long division to approximate the first 10000 digits of phi, etc.

Multiprocessing is expensive here because all objects sent to workers are serialized (using pickle), then sent sequentially to each worker using an inter-process-communication (IPC) method (generally memory-bound for large datasets), read by each the worker (which can likely starve for data to compute), then unserialized (unpickling) before just doing a basic addition. Cost(pickling+IPC+unpickling) > Cost(addition).

Multithreading can help to avoid this problem but it is limited due to the GIL which prevent any speed up for computational operations unless it is disabled. It can be disabled by a C module when no Python objects are manipulated (quite rare). Alternatively, it can be experimentally disabled globally on very-recent version of Python. However, this introduce some additional overhead (eg. 5% slowdown of sequential codes) and is not supported by all native modules either. It might cause issues (eg. crash) with some modules, so use at your own risks.

The main point is that Python is not really well designed for parallel codes (at least to make pure-Python code runs in parallel). Running slow pure-Python code in parallel is far from being great. If you care about performance (which is often why you write parallel codes), then it is often better to use vectorized code first (either using specialized modules like Numpy/SciPy or compiler-based Numba/Cython ones). Then you can often better run this in parallel. In Numba/Cython, you can write multithreaded code without any GIL limitation (but cannot manipulate pure-Python objects in it still).

@JérômeRichard what happened to the answer that was describing the pickiling a unpickling overhead of python multiprocessing.pool ; it seemed a good answer and interesting matter for me but it has vanished ??

@pippo1980 It has been deleted by its author. IDK why... Btw, I do not think the advise about files was a good idea. IPC is done in-memory while big files are typically stored on HDD/SSD storage device which are always slower than the RAM (on any decent machine configuration).

I modified your fun1:
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

def fun1( x ):
    y = 0
    for i in range( len( x ) ):
        
        if 0.3 < x[i] < 0.5:
            y = y + x[i]
            
        
        elif x[i] >= 0.5:
            
            y += x[i]**2
            
        else:
            
            y += 1
        
    return( y )

def fun2( x ):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool( 2 )
    y1, y2 = p.map( fun1, [ x[ : len( x ) // 2 ], x[ len( x ) // 2 : ] ] )
    y = y1 + y2
    return( y )

x = [ random.random() for i in range( 10 ** 6 ) ]

st = time.time()
ans = fun1( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

st = time.time()
ans = fun2( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

x = [ random.random() for i in range( 10 ** 7 ) ]

st = time.time()
ans = fun1( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

st = time.time()
ans = fun2( x )
et = time.time()
print( f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}." )

output, seems reproducible to me (I've a small CPU):
time = 0.5544326305389404, answer = 671883.5322289083.
time = 0.5338046550750732, answer = 671883.5322288958.
time = 4.955313205718994, answer = 6715366.44807873.
time = 3.6769814491271973, answer = 6715366.448078716.

#anoter try:

time = 0.5013079643249512, answer = 671620.2326088196.
time = 0.39491748809814453, answer = 671620.2326088334.
time = 4.901585578918457, answer = 6717295.294786744.
time = 3.776726484298706, answer = 6717295.294786792.

#next:

time = 0.4863710403442383, answer = 671647.0603678812.
time = 0.6218230724334717, answer = 671647.0603678576.
time = 5.027068376541138, answer = 6716671.888051354.
time = 3.752805471420288, answer = 6716671.888051517.

I think it is related to Understanding time complexity with Python examples

but I could be wrong. I am trying to learn too.
Addendum
As per a previous good answer that was deleted:
using Multiprocessing.Pool().map as from Multiprocessing in Python - all about pickling 

Multiprocessing in Python is flexible. You can either define Processes and orchestrate them as you wishes, or use one of excellent methods herding Pool of processes. By default Pool assumes number of processes to be equal to number of CPU cores, but you can change it by passing processes parameter. Main methods included in Pool are apply and map, which let you run process with arbitrary arguments or execute parallel map, respectively. There are also asynchronous versions of these, i.e. apply_async and map_async.Simple, right? Yes, this is all what's needed. Now, go and use multiprocessing!
Actually, before you leave to follow your dreams there's a small caveat to this. When executing processes Python first pickles these methods. This create a bottleneck as only objects that are pickle will be passed to processes. Moreover, Pool doesn't allow to parallelize objects that refer to the instance of pool which runs them.
Yes, this is all because of Pickle. What can you do with it? In a sense, not much, as it's the default battery-included solution. On the other, pickle is generally slow

Deleted answer:

You are copying considerably large amount of data (>90MB), so fun2 is consuming a lot of time for data copying (serialize/deserilaize, inter-process communication),
>>> import pickle
>>> import random
>>> datea = [random.random() for i in range(10 ** 7)]
>>> len(pickle.dumps(data)
90032371

Instead of passing large data directly, you can store your data in multiple files, and distribuite file names to workers.
You may want to use parallel computing framework (such as Polars, Dask and Ray), depending on your workload.


When multiprocessing, your list has to be serialised. This is achieved using pickle. When the length of your list is 10**7 the in-memory size of the list is 89,095,160. The serialised object is slightly larger at 90,032,371. That 90MB object is written to disk (in some temporary location) then consumed prior to execution of your function. That is a relatively slow process.
You can improve matters slightly by not serialising to disk. Instead you can use shared memory although that still won't be as fast as the linear execution - i.e., when fun1() is called directly
Here's a variation of your code that demonstrates the 3 techniques, prints the object sizes and outputs the various timings:
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import pickle
import sys


def fun1(x):
    return sum(x)


def fun2(x):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        data = [x[: len(x) // 2], x[len(x) // 2 :]]
        return sum(p.map(fun1, data))


def fun3(name):
    shm = SharedMemory(name)
    try:
        x = pickle.loads(shm.buf)
        return fun1(x)
    finally:
        shm.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = [random.random() for i in range(10**7)]
    size = sys.getsizeof(x)
    print(f"In-memory {size=:,}")
    try:
        smb = pickle.dumps(x)
        size = len(smb)
        print(f"Pickled object {size=:,}")
        shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=size)
        shm.buf[:size] = smb
        for func in fun1, fun2:
            st = time.perf_counter()
            ans = func(x)
            et = time.perf_counter()
            print(func.__name__, f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}.")
        st = time.perf_counter()
        ans = fun3(shm.name)
        et = time.perf_counter()
        print(fun3.__name__, f"time = {et - st}, answer = {ans}.")
    finally:
        shm.close()
        shm.unlink()

Output:
In-memory size=89,095,160
Pickled object size=90,032,371
fun1 time = 0.21793299994897097, answer = 4999444.726535229.
fun2 time = 0.6652624170528725, answer = 4999444.726535082.
fun3 time = 0.4321752089308575, answer = 4999444.726535229.

Note:
Your results may differ due to platform and Python version differences.
Here the platform is:
Python 3.13.0
MacOS 15.1.1
Apple M2


"That 90MB object is written to disk" I am not convinced by this. AFAIK this is not true and done in-memory. Do you have an official source confirming this claim? (note that on systems like Linux or Mac a file might be used for IPC, but data are not physically stored on any storage devices; the kind of IPC method used can impact performance independently of the actual physical kind of storage used)

@JérômeRichard  I had written a separate test (which I'm happy to share with you) where I used implicit pickling versus explicit use of shared memory to pass data to a subprocess. The latter test proved to be significantly faster than the former. I deduced that this was probably due to disk I/O. That may be a flawed assertion. If I am incorrect then there's something seriously wrong with Python's pickling strategy / implementation.

Is it relevant to topic Why does python multiprocessing pickle objects to pass objects between processes?

The timings does not prove data are written to the disk. In fact, I profiled this on my Linux and for 10 run of fun2 and fun3, I measured a SSD throughput of <0.05 MiB/s (certainly due to modules being loaded). This prove that, on Linux, with multiprocessing, nearly nothing is read/store from/to the storage device!

Actually, I think your benchmark is biased : multiprocessing must pickle+unpickle data and your shared-memory benchmark only measure the time to unpickle it but not the time to pickle/dump data. On my Linux machine, fun2 takes 0.60 sec, fun3 takes 0.32 sec, pickle.dumps takes 0.13 sec, and the shared-memory copy takes 0.04 sec. In the end, the complete shared-memory timing is 0.32+0.13+0.04=0.49 sec (as opposed to 0.60. This is still faster but not so much : only 1.22 times faster.

A quick profiling analysis tends to show that this performance gap is certainly due to page faults. This make sense since fun3 runs serially in the same process while fun2 use multiple processes so there is another bias in the benchmark! Indeed, each process needs to read data from another process resulting in expensive page fault while the pages faults are not needed during reads in the same process because the previous copy already did it. This under-estimate the page fault overhead by a factor of 2 (probably 0.03-0.04 sec).

In the end, the benchmark is biased and the problem has nothing to do with "serialising to disk"! If we consider all overheads (including page faults and the time to create/join processes, reload modules, etc. -- that is certainly 0.025-0.040 sec), then the shared memory is not much faster here: only ~1.1 times. Shared memory can be a bit faster if it is reused which is not the case. It can also help for Numpy array to avoid pickling. Based on profiling results, as it stands, this answer is essentially wrong.
